# Select random data with DataMapper

Tags: mysql, ruby, datamapper

Im trying to select random datasets with DataMapper, but seems like there is no such function support.

For example, i have set of data:

```
+-------------------+
| ID | Name | Value |
+-------------------+
| 1  | T1   | 123   |
| 2  | T2   | 456   |
| 3  | T3   | 789   |
| 4  | T4   | 101   |
| ----------------- |
| N  | Tn   | value |
```

There can be a lot of data, more than 100k rows.

And i need to map data to object:

```
class Item
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :value, String
end
```

So, the question is: How to select random data from table?

Similar query in SQL will be:

```
SELECT id, name, value FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT n;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate a random number x < number_of_rows, and just fetch that id.

You could also try entering the SQL directly, like this:

```
find_by_sql(<<-SQL
    SELECT `id`, `name`, `value` FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT n;
SQL, :properties => property_set)
```

You need to specify :properties though, for it to map with your property set.

Comment: But what if i have sequence of Id` like this: 1, 3300, 91928, 234 ?
And im more interested how to fetch dataset, not only separate rows.

Comment: Updated the answer with another solution

Answer (score 6):

A long time after the OP, but since this is the first google hit for "datamapper random row"...

Using pure DataMapper, and without making assumptions about continuous IDs, etc, you can do:

```
Item.first(:offset => rand(Item.count))
```

which results in the queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `items`
SELECT <fields> FROM `items` ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 1 OFFSET <n>
```

If you'd prefer a single query, at the cost of potentially reduced speed, you can do:

```
Item.all.sample
```

while results in:

```
SELECT <fields> FROM `items` ORDER BY `id`
```

Obviously, wrap this in a transaction if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

I generally don't care literally retrieving random records. In this case, I use a slighttly different paradigm.

1. ORDER BY value // or value mod some number // you could also use name, or some function on the name
2. SELECT LIMIT n OFFSET k

where k is a random number generated in your code less than N-n. Sufficiently random for most cases, even though the records are somewhat contiguous in what you use for ORDER BY.